# Windows User Profile and Java

Tags: java, windows, maven, environment-variables

I'm using Maven, and it stores local repository under user home folder.
I decided to move my user profile from `C:\Users\Dany` to `D:\Users\Dany` to save my SSD disk space. Also I changed several keys in windows registry.
All works fine but Maven still save artifacts to `C:\Users\Dany\.m2\repository`.

I **know** how to change local repository location in `settings.xml`.
But could somebody explain Maven's behaviour?

P.S.
IntelliJ IDEA also saves its data to `C:\Users\Dany\.IntelliJIdea11`.

**UPD**
`System.getProperty("user.home");` returns `C:\Users\Dany`.

**UPD2**
`set USERPROFILE` in windows comand line says `USERPROFILE=D:\Users\Dany`.

**UPD3**
Question is about how Java gets user home folder location but not about how to set Maven repository location

Comment: I've been wanting to move my profile and Maven became a reason

Comment: could you print the value of System.getProperty("user.home") from a program run inside your intelliJIDEA IDE? Maven resolves the local repository location w.r.t this JVM environment variable.

Comment: Of course. It prints "C:\Users\Dany"

Comment: What is the value of your `USERPROFILE` environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows Java gets the user.home property from the registry:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Desktop
then it removes the last folder.

For example: %userprofile%\Desktop => %userprofile%

This is (will be) fixed in Java 8.

Until then, the solution is to add this into the environment variables:
_JAVA_OPTIONS:-Duser.home=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%

or in command line: set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Duser.home=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%

I saw the solution in the comments of this page:
http://www.timehat.com/javas-user-home-is-wrong-on-windows/

Answer (score 1):

I got the question. Just run into the exactly the same issue. I found the answer [here](http://www.timehat.com/javas-user-home-is-wrong-on-windows/), then I also found the related [bug entry](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4787931) too.

Comment: Lone links are [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Put a settings.xml file into D:\Users\Dany.m2\ and put something like this into your settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>D:/WhatEverLocationYouWant</localRepository

</settings>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to change local repository location in settings.xml. But why all Java apps point to old location? My environment variables are OK.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to update the [<localRepository> setting](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Simple_Values) in the *settings.xml* in your home folder.

Next, you need to update the *M2_REPO* environmental variable to point to the new location. You may also need to set it for individual [Eclipse projects](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html#Maven_2_repository), either by using maven itself or setting the environmental variable from the Eclipse settings.

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. By defaulf Maven stores its repo in Home user profile folder. I've changed it, also changed windows registry, my enviroment variables point to new location. But Maven (IDEA, Eclipse) thinks that home folder is at old location! why? May be during JDK installing Java saves current home folder location and then uses it? I have no idea.

Comment: Both Eclipse and IntelliJ have settings that allows you to specify the location of your local repo. Have you tried to set them?

Comment: Yes, and it works. But when I run `mvn compile` for example - it saves to location configured in settings.xml. Question is about how Java gets user home folder but not about how to set repository location.

Answer (score 0):

If you have NTFS on both partitions, you could just create a symlink from D:\Users\Dany to C:\Users\Dany. Software won't see any difference.